# JsPDF Button arrow

Tags: jspdf

I was trying to build a button arrow using jsPDF and couldn't find anything either in the docs or here on stackoverflow. So I created a function which creates one exactly as I want and I want to share it to you in the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
function createArrow(doc, x, y, w, l, c, s) {
    const coef = w * 0.175 / 0.5;
    doc.setLineWidth(w);
    doc.setDrawColor(c);
    doc.line(x - l, y - l, x + coef, y + coef, s);
    doc.line(x + coef, y - coef, x - l, y + l, s);
}

const doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', [223, 157]);
      doc.createArrow(20, 20, 0.5, 1.2, '#000000', 'FD');
      doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
```

And here I want to explain how this works. The function accepts 7 parameters:

```
1. doc = document
2. x   = top of the angle x axis
3. y   = top of the angle y axis
4. w   = width of the arrow
5. l   = length of the arrow
6. c   = color of the arrow
7. s   = style of the arrow (S - stroke, F - fill, FD - fill then stroke)
```

If you wonder what is the ussage for the `coef` it is there to fix the top of the angle which it will not look good at a simple intersection of 2 lines without a little adjustment.